# the like button on my apps likes a link back to my server, not the facebook page

Tags: facebook, url, iframe, facebook-like

I have created a couple of iframe apps. they can be seen here.
www.facebook.com/iancareyfanpage

I have created some iframe apps and inserted the following to display a like and comments section.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=123543567752303"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId : '123543567752303',
status : true,
cookie : true,
xfbml : true
});
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
<fb:comments width="500"></fb:comments>
```

However, when someone clicks the like button or leaves a comment the link back takes you to my actual webserver and displays the iframe app like a webpage, i need to change the url that gets put on peoples pages. sorry if i'm not explaining myself very well, hopefully someone will understand what I mean.

Comment: for the like button, set the `href` attribute to your Facebook page.

Comment: @ifaour, it should be defined for comments plugin as well to achieve same effect

Answer (score 0):

You should use `href` attribute to `<fb:comments>` tag.

See XFBML example on [Comments Plugin documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)